# How to display storyblok story on website using javascript

Tags: php, storyblok

Hello I am working with storyblok headless cams

specifically using the content delivery api https://github.com/storyblok/storyblok-php-client#content-delivery-api

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use Storyblok\Client as StoryblokClient; // you can use also an alias
$client = new StoryblokClient('#');
$data = $client->getStoryBySlug('tomandjerry')->getBody();
// access to the body response...
print_r($data["story"]);

echo $data["cv"] . PHP_EOL;
print_r($data["rels"]);
print_r($data["links"]);
```

gaining access to the above story, how do I preview the story on my custom website as described by this documentation `https://www.storyblok.com/docs/guide/essentials/visual-editor`

Comment: https://github.com/storyblok/storyblok-php-client#%E2%84%B9%EF%B8%8F-more-resources - please contact the software vendor for your support options, it often does not work well to request support for third-party documentation on stackoverflow. For the general context, please see [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)